# Lua - local required eveytime a local variable is assigned?

Tags: lua

I've found a strange piece of code in the Lua documentation :

```
function trim8(s)
  local i1,i2 = find(s,'^%s*')
  if i2 >= i1 then s = sub(s,i2+1) end
  local i1,i2 = find(s,'%s*$')
  if i2 >= i1 then s = sub(s,1,i1-1) end
  return s
end
```

Why is `local` used once again with `i1` and `i2`? Aren't they already declared among local variables? Do you have to repeat the `local` keyword every time you want to assign them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to use `local` over and over. The variables `i1` and `i2` will be `local` in the scope of the function because of the first line itself.

While it should not be done, there is nothing wrong with defining the same variables over and over. It will just assign a new position in stack to the newer, and shadow the older one.

The following is the instruction output for a simple function:

```
function t()
    local i = 2
    local i = 3
end
t()
```

```
function <temp.lua:1,4> (3 instructions, 12 bytes at 00658990)
0 params, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 2 locals, 2 constants, 0 functions
        1       [2]     LOADK           0 -1    ; 2
        2       [3]     LOADK           1 -2    ; 3
        3       [4]     RETURN          0 1
```

and updating the second `local i = 3` to just `i = 3`:

```
function t()
    local i = 2
    i = 3
end
t()
```

```
function <temp.lua:1,4> (3 instructions, 12 bytes at 00478990)
0 params, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 1 local, 2 constants, 0 functions
        1       [2]     LOADK           0 -1    ; 2
        2       [3]     LOADK           0 -2    ; 3
        3       [4]     RETURN          0 1
```

Notice the difference at the second instruction.

---

Apart from that, the function is quite inefficient. You can instead use the following:

```
function Trim(sInput)
    return sInput:match "^%s*(.-)%s*$"
end
```

Comment: Stack positions (local variables) are not subject to garbage collection.  A value stored in shadowed local variable is still regarded as being accessible.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Do you have a specification reference for that or is it that based on observation? (I know I have seen shadowed locals in the standard implementation while writing a debugger.) But, is a compiler not free to optimize stack usage?

Comment: @TomBlodget - IMO, it's very unlikely that stack optimization would be useful for typical Lua programs.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, using `local` or not in the second *declaration* are not equivalent. Using a second `local` would declare another variable.

However in your example code, they have basically the same. Check these simpler code:

```
local a = 0
local a = 1
```

and

```
local a = 0
a = 1
```

Use `luac -p -l` outputs the following result:

```
0+ params, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 2 locals, 2 constants, 0 functions
    1   [1] LOADK       0 -1    ; 0
    2   [2] LOADK       1 -2    ; 1
    3   [2] RETURN      0 1
```

and

```
0+ params, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 1 local, 2 constants, 0 functions
    1   [1] LOADK       0 -1    ; 0
    2   [2] LOADK       0 -2    ; 1
    3   [2] RETURN      0 1
```

Comment: heh, I just updated my reply with the `luac -l` output =P

Comment: Thanks for your help. So which is the variable referenced by the identifier 'a' when you declare 'a' twice ? The second one that was declared ?

Comment: @Virus721 After the entire statement that declares the second one, it would be the second one, For example `local a = 0; local a = a + 1` would assign the value 0+1 to the second variable.